# First user by category

Tags: sql, postgresql, partition

How can I count the new users for each category who bought in the category for the first by year? For instance, 2015-2020 by year, if someone bought in 2015 for the first it will be counted as a new uesr in 2015 but not in 2016-2020.

Table_1 (Columns: product_name, date, category, sales, user_id)

Want to get the result as bleow

[image]

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: It is postgre SQL :)

Answer (score 0):

You’ll want to start with a sub query to get the first date each user purchased in the category. This is a pretty straightforward `group by` problem:

```
select 
user_id, 
category, 
min(date) as first_category_purchase
from my_table 
group by user_id, category;
```

Next, you can use Postgres’s `date_trunc` function to group by year and category, using your first query as a sub query:

```
select
category,
date_trunc('year', first_category_purchase)
count(*)
from (
select 
user_id, 
category, 
min(date) as first_category_purchase
from my_table 
group by user_id, category
) a 
group by 1, 2;
```

Comment: Absolutely. Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, one method is `group by` after a `distinct on`:

```
select date, count(*) as num_new_users
from (select distinct on (user_id, category) t.*
      from t
      order by user_id, category, date asc
     ) d
group by date
order by date;
```

If `date` is really a date and not a year, then you need something like `to_char()` or `date_trunc()` to convert it to a year.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It seems a great way and could you please advise if I want to apply this in Big query? If I can't use 'Distinct on' function?

Comment: @MKMK_79 . . . This question is tagged Postgres.  If you want an answer for BigQuery, then ask a *new* question and tag it appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Will tag the appropriate one!